# Regex get word between strings JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a return value of "SomeCode SomeAddressHere SecondAddressHere, SomeCityHere, SomeCountryHere"

Would like to get the **SomeCityHere**, my current regex is this

```
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
var str2 = str2.match(/(?<= )([^,]+)/)[0];
console.log(str2);
```

I would like to return **California** but I cant seem to get it.

Anyone knows any workaround?

Comment: if you add `/g` for global  it is the second match `var str2 = str2.match(/(?<= )([^,]+)/g);
    console.log(str2[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match what you need because

- `(?<= )` matches a location right after a space and then
- `([^,]+)` captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than a comma.

In a string like `SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA`, the match occurs right after the first space and goes up to the first comma, i.e. [`Los Angeles City`](https://regex101.com/r/HUDSI5/1).

It seems you may use a non-regex solution(s) like [user984003 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61425533/3832970), but in case your `SomeCodeHere`  or `SomeAddressHere` or `SecondAddressHere` may contain commas, too, you may consider getting the value between the last two commas:

```
/[^\s,][^,]*(?=,[^,]*$)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HUDSI5/3).

**Details**

- `[^\s,]` - a char other than whitespace and a comma
- `[^,]*` - 0+ chars other than a comma
- `(?=,[^,]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a comma and then 0+ chars other than a comma (`[^,]*`) till the end of the string (`$`).

JS demo:

```js
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
var match = str2.match(/[^\s,][^,]*(?=,[^,]*$)/);
if (match) console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be regex:

```
var str2 = str2.split(",")[1].trim();
```

or

```
var str2 = str2.split(", ")[1];
```

Comment: Gave a second case if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

This is little varient from yours where I used both Look ahead positive and Look behind positive

```
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
var str2 = str2.match(/(?<=, ).+(?=,)/)[0]
console.log(str2) // California
```